# How to style a horizontal submenu with CSS?

Tags: css, menu, drop-down-menu

Im barely a novice with list menus. I have a vertical menu with its own CSS. I've tried many different options to make a horizontal submenu with it's own styling. I've run into trouble in  every way I've tried. So I've semi aborted it.

This is what I've got going on. It's a bastardized way of doing it...or may be it's not even going to work www.CAITMIZZI.COM/home.html

The problem I'm having is making the submenu link work without dissrupting the main menu. I'm POSITIVE I'm doing this wrong and there is a simpler solution. Have a look and let me know pls.

Thanks

Here is the CSS - note the .sub_menu is how is was trying to style before. I'm using the hoverable class now

```
#MenuWrapper{
    width: 550px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: 60px;
    z-index: 9;
    height: 540px;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
#Menu {
    font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
    font-size:125px;
    line-height: 105px;
    height: 540px;
    width: 550px;
    z-index: 8;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #CCC;
}
#Menu a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #9CC;
    }
#Menu ul {margin:0; padding:0;}
#Menu li {
        list-style: none;}
#Menu li a:hover {
    color: #CCFF00;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
.sub_menu{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #903;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.hoverable {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.hoverable div {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 50px;
    left: 425px;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 1em;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #903;
}

a.hoverable:hover div {
    display: block;
}
```

here is the layout

```
<div id="MenuWrapper">
        <div id="Menu">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
        <li><a href="beauty.html" class="hoverable">Portfolio<div> > beauty | fashion | grooming | advertising</div></a></li>
        <li><a href="bridal.html">Bridal</a></li>
        <li><a href="client_list.html">Client List</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Diodeus/jejNy/